# Cannot use file i\o when running mpi

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have a problem in **MPI**, when I run my MPI program from wmpiexec I **cannot make any file io**. But when I run it in **visual studio** it works fine.
I tried the usual see `fopen()` as well as the mpi APIs nothing works.
(the file already exists)

```
/* This is an interactive version of cpi */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int  namelen, numprocs, rank;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_File fh;
    char x='x';

    if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, "test.txt", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
        //FILE* f = fopen("test.txt","wb+");
        //if(f==NULL){
        //printf("failed to open file\n");exit(1);
        //}
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            char buf[42];
            //fprintf(f,"%d \n",i);
            snprintf(buf, 42, "%d \n", i);
            MPI_File_read(fh,&x,sizeof(char), MPI_CHAR, &status);
            printf("%c",x);


        }
        getchar();
        //        fclose(f);
        MPI_File_close(&fh);
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path?

Comment: is there any error message ? did you test the return status of `MPI_File_open()` and `MPI_File_read()` ? why do you need to `getchar()` ? if the MPI task running on the same node invoking `wmpiexec` ? or an other node with a different filesystem ?

Answer (score 0):

**The error code returned by the function [`MPI_File_open()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php) can be tested** to know why the opening of the file failed. Indeed, as underlined in the documentation of this function:

> For MPI I/O function errors, the default error handler is set to MPI_ERRORS_RETURN. The error handler may be changed with MPI_File_set_errhandler; the predefined error handler MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL may be used to make I/O errors fatal. Note that MPI does not guarantee that an MPI program can continue past an error.

As a result **the default behavior of [`MPI_File_open()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php) is not to report errors and try to keep going**, even if the file does not exist. Therefore, retreiving the value of the error code and tunning the error handler seems a promissing way to investigate the issue. Here is a sample code code based on yours doing so. It can be compiled by `mpicc main.c -o main -std=c99 -Wall` and run by `mpirun -np 2 main`

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// A custom error handler
void file_errhandler_fn(MPI_File * file, int * errorcode, ... );

void file_errhandler_fn(MPI_File * file, int * errorcode, ... ){

    if(*errorcode!=MPI_SUCCESS){
        //your error handler here...
        char error[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING+1];
        int errorlen;
        MPI_Error_string(*errorcode, error, &errorlen);
        fprintf(stderr,"error handler: %s\n",error);
        fflush(stderr);
        //visible painful death, easily spotted
        exit(1);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int  namelen, numprocs, rank;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_File fh;

    //creating an error handler for the file, calling your custom function:
    MPI_Errhandler errhandler;
    MPI_File_create_errhandler(file_errhandler_fn, &errhandler);


    char x='x';

    if (rank == 0) {
        int errorcode=MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, "test.txt", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
        //in case the opening of the file went wrong, handle the error:
        if(errorcode!=MPI_SUCCESS){
            //your error handler here...
            char error[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING+1];
            int errorlen;
            MPI_Error_string(errorcode, error, &errorlen);
            fprintf(stderr,"opening file: %s\n",error);
            fflush(stderr);
            //visible painful death, easily spotted
            exit(1);
        }
        //setting custom error handlerr for further operations
        errorcode=MPI_File_set_errhandler(fh,errhandler);


        //FILE* f = fopen("test.txt","wb+");
        //if(f==NULL){
        //printf("failed to open file\n");exit(1);
        //}
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            char buf[42];
            //fprintf(f,"%d \n",i);
            snprintf(buf, 42, "%d \n", i);
            errorcode=MPI_File_read(fh,&x,sizeof(char), MPI_CHAR, &status);
            printf("index %d got %c",i,x);

            // the following line should compile fine, but triggers MPI_ERR_COUNT, captured by the custom error handler. 
            //errorcode=MPI_File_write(fh, &i, -1, MPI_INT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); 


        }
        getchar();
        //        fclose(f);
        MPI_File_close(&fh);
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }

    MPI_Errhandler_free(&errhandler);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Doing so may not fully solve your issue, but it provides a way to investigate the issue. What is the value of the error code? If it does not help you, let me know so I can suppress my answer an leave your question unnanswered!